# Project Euler #2 in Go

Tags: programming-challenge, multithreading, matrix, go

I just learned Go (yesterday in fact) and today I made this solution to [Project Euler #2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2).  The problem is to sum the even [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).  My program uses the matrix representation of the linear relation between consecutive Fibonacci numbers to calculate the coefficients for an equation.  This equation will generate the next even Fibonacci number and the one before it from an even one and the one before it.  However, it skips n - 1 even Fibonacci numbers where n is the number of cores so each core has its own set of data to work with.  So the problem and implementation are rather mathematical.

The program worked perfectly the first time I ran it, however, it is slower than a nonparallel C implementation.  I think this is because on my computer using 4 goroutines, each goroutine runs about 3 loops so the overhead from creating the goroutines and calculating the coefficients (which involves matrix math, but only at startup) is not offset.  The only matrix calculation is raising a matrix to the power of 4, which I did using [this Go matrix library](https://github.com/gonum/matrix) which I believe uses BLAS under the hood.

```
/* p2.go
 * by hacatu
 * 
 * This program solves Project Euler problem 2, to find the sum of the even Fibonacci numbers under 4000000.
 * The Fibbonacci number F[k + 2] = F[k + 1] + F[k].  This leads to the linear transformation matrix ((1, 1), (1, 0))
 * (F[k + 2], F[k + 1]) = ((1, 1), (1, 0))*(F[k + 1], F[k]).  Every third Fibonacci number is even, so cube the matrix
 * and get ((3, 2), (2, 1))
 * (F[k + 4], F[k + 3]) = ((3, 2), (2, 1))*(F[k + 1], F[k]).  To parallelize this, raise the matrix to the power of the number
 * of cores and start each core at an offset from (F[k + 1], F[k]) = (2, 1) by applying the ((3, 2), (2, 1)) transformation
 * repeatedly.
 * (F[k + 3*n + 1], F[k + 3*n]) = ((3, 2), (2, 1))^n*(F[k + 1], F[k]).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number.
 */
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "github.com/gonum/matrix/mat64"
)

func round(f float64) int {
    return int(f + 0.5)
}

/* Calculates the appropriate power of the next-even transformation matrix
 * and returns the coefficients in the linear equation it represents.
 */
func calcTMat(n int) (aa, ab, ba, bb int) {
    t1Mat := mat64.NewDense(2, 2, []float64{3, 2, 2, 1})
    tMat := new(mat64.Dense)
    tMat.Pow(t1Mat, n);

    return round(tMat.At(0, 0)),
           round(tMat.At(0, 1)),
           round(tMat.At(1, 0)),
           round(tMat.At(1, 1))
}

func main() {
    cpus := runtime.NumCPU()
    fmt.Printf("Running on %d cores.\n", cpus)

    sums := make(chan int, cpus)

    aa, ab, ba, bb := calcTMat(cpus)

    fmt.Printf("Using transformation a, b = %d*a + %d*b, %d*a + %d*b.\n", aa, ab, ba, bb)

    for a, b, i := 2, 1, 0; i < cpus; a, b, i = 3*a + 2*b, 2*a + b, i + 1 {
        go func(a, b int){
            sum := 0
            for a < 4000000 {
                sum += a
                a, b = aa*a + ab*b, ba*a + bb*b
            }
            sums <- sum
        }(a, b)
    }

    sum := 0
    for i := 0; i < cpus; i++ {
        sum += <-sums
    }

    fmt.Println("The sum of the even Fibonacci number under 4000000 is", sum);
}
```

Is this code good Go (understandable considering what it does, efficient, and idiomatic), and how can I make it faster (redesign or compiler flags)?